# Error 500 in IIS 10 Express with .NET Core 2.0 Angular2 website

Tags: .net-core, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I've created a .NET Core 2.0 Angular2 website using Visual Studio 2017's template. When deploying the site to my local machine's IIS (IIS 10 Express) using Web Deploy, the site runs fine. When doing the same on our server, Win server 2016 (same IIS version) and browsing the site, error 500 is given.

I've checked the host files for both machines, nothing significantly different regarding IIS and site setup. Exact same permissions and deployment files. Application pool updated to No Managed Code. Core Hosting Bundle installed, node installed.

I followed a few tutorials on enabling error logging, but get "Warning: Could not create stdoutLogFile ...., ErrorCode = -2147024893" in the event viewer when trying to browse the site.

Has anyone else had similar issues when deploying to Win server 2016?

Comment: Check the event log for exceptions

Comment: Did you check the instructions and common errors list in the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: Esp the `Restart the system or execute net stop was /y followed by net start w3svc` step

Comment: What is the line number showed in the 500 error page? You probably hit an OOB issue, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/oob-500.html